# I want to upgrade my ram, but am confused

Tags: memory

I have an HP Laptop Model 15-F085wm.  I want to install 2x 8 GB ram sticks of ddr3l 1600. I don't know if my windows 10 home x64 base system will recognize 16 gb. I know it has 2 ddr3l slots.

Comment: Windows 10 Home x64 can recognize up to 128GB of RAM.  The limiting factor would be your laptop.  Use the scanner at http://www.crucial.com to find out what your laptop can support.

Answer (score 4):

as twisty said, the home x64 version supports up to 128gb max.

the HP Model 15-F085wm supports a maximum of 16 Gigabytes of ddr3-1600 memory.

(Two 8 gig sticks)

[Instructions to install memory modules in the HP 15 series.](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04763947)